# How to stack multiple materials onto arbitrary shape

Tags: modifiers

I have an object of this form:
[image]

It is just the standard cube and standard sphere put together with the boolean modifier (union). I would like to add materials on top which follows the shape of the object, meaning adding a given thickness parallel to the z axis. My first guess was using the solidify modifier, but it should only go in one direction, and I also want to change to a different material for the solidified material and finally I would like to stack multiple materials like this.

In the ideal case those additional materials are only covering half of the top plane, indicated by the green area here:
[image]

But if that's too complicated I can also cut the cube/sphere in half and only apply it to one side.

Is solidify the right direction or is there a different, better suited modifier and how would I achieve the desired result?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If I understand correctly, why don't you just use another cube and boolean modifier on top of your existing shape?

Comment: The top materials will be transparent, so I need the layers to actually follow the shape of the sphere.

Comment: Then just select all the vertices on the top and extrude them out vertically.  You can then apply whatever material you want.  Or, if you want it to be a separate object, simply duplicate your cube/sphere and delete what you don't need.

Comment: I thought about the latter option, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution... But as it will do the trick I guess it will be fine! Thank you very much for your help!